# move buffer to next subtree in org-mode when narrowed - C-x n s

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is there a way to move to next/previous heading, same level when (C-c C-f/b) when buffer is narrowed to subtree (C-x n s)?

Say I have the following outline

```
* First
** item A 
** item B
* Second
** item A2 
** item B2
```

and I got to `* First` and narrow with `C-x n s` now I only see:

```
* First
** item A 
** item B
```

If I try to *move to next/previous heading* with `C-c C-f/b` I can't. I would like to be able to move back and forth between subtrees in a folded (narrowed) three. How can I do this?

Comment: I like to use `org-forward-element` and `org-backward-element` -- perhaps you will like it also.  If on a main heading, it jumps to the next/previous main heading.  If on a subheading, it jumps to the next/previous subheading.

Comment: thank you for your response, but if I'm narrowed down to `* First` it only takes me to `** item B` not to `* Second`. Makes sense?

Comment: You would need a function that widens, then moves forwards or backwards, and then narrows to the new region.   It is doable, but not built-in to my knowledge.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks, I will try working on that.